# Auto Completion in Pycharm for Robot framework

Tags: pycharm, robotframework

I am trying to develop scripts using Robot framework with Pycharm IDE(2017.3.6 - Community Edition) and have added the plugins Intellibot(0.10.143.381)and Robot Framework support(0.16.4).
Python Version 2.7.14
Robot Libraries version [image]

I have a list of files in my scripts

1. Variable File
2. Common Keyword file(consisting of common methods used)
   FileName **Comman_Handlers.txt**

My method as follows

**WaitForELement**

[Arguments]    ${Locator}

Set Browser Implicit Wait    3

Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    10sec    1sec    Element Should Be Visible ${Locator}

3. Feature specific file(having references of common methods and specif methods for the feature)

I will access the method used in the previous file as

**Comman_Handlers.WaitForELement**    ${Locator}

I am referencing the file using a relative path

..\Infrastructure\Comman_Handlers.txt

4. Test case file

My problem is

1. I am not able to navigate to the definition of the method Comman_Handlers.WaitForELement (No usages found in all places are found) is shown. The same works for me in sublime.
2. I am expecting auto completion for the keywords which are already available in the libraries such as ExtendedSelenium2Library,Excel2Library and for the content which were already typed(for example a variable declared in the previous step)

Kindly provide a me a glimpse on where am getting it wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

For Robot Framework integration in PyCharm, make sure you're using the [IntelliBot @SeleniumLibary Patched](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10700-intellibot-seleniumlibrary-patched) plugin.

There are other Robot Framework plugins for Pycharm and IntelliBot is no longer supported by the original developer, but it's still the best RF plugin out there so far (I've tried them all).

The recent *SeleniumLibrary Patched* version is a fork with a Selenium 3 fix for the Selenium library from Robot Framework, which has some dynamic keywords that were not being imported correctly in the original plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm -->  FIle --> Settings --> Project Interpreter --> Install robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.3.1 (Uninstall the latest (4.1.0)) --> OK and restart Pycharm IDE

It seems that seleniumlibrary has some issues with latest versions (4.0.0)

it worked for me